# Getting request and storage statistics for S3 Object

Tags: amazon-s3

My application bills on the number of requests an object gets and since a collection of objects belong to my customer, I need to get usage statistics on the objects that customer owns. I need to know things like, how much storage space that person is taking along with how my get requests is performed on that object and charge accordingly. Is it possible to get this functionality in S3 Node SDK?